# Signed value calculation logic for hex value

Tags: c, hex

**unsigned Int** value of 0xfb is **251**.

**0xfb = (15 * 16) + 11**

How is the anomalous **signed value for 0xfb** which **-5** derived from ?

Comment: Becasue you assigned that value to a (signed) `char`? Please show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Because of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation of negative numbers and ***sign extension***? What did you *expect* it to be?

Comment: If you only keep one byte, what's `0xFB + 5`?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. _"signed value of 0xfb"_ does not make much sense without context.

Comment: @user202729 A `signed int` must be capable of holding at least the range [−32,767, +32,767] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

Answer (score 1):

The value (-5) is represented in two's complement.

> 0x00           signed value:0
>   0x01           signed value:1
>   ....
>   0x7F           signed value:127
>   0x80           signed value:-128
>   ....
>   0xFB           signed value -5
>   ...
>   0xFF           signed value:-1

so a signed integer 8 Bit value is good for -128 to 127

Comment: Please provide a derivation for this value.

Comment: Which value? For details have a look here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)